# Evaluating Coldfusion directory path for file existence

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I've been working on a script for a couple of weeks tweaking it as need be to track CGI.script_PATH and CGI.REFERER on an older coldfusion install which has over 500 .cfc and .cfm pages. I just hit a snag in my code. It doesn't capture a page name in the CGI.Referer variable when the referer is a folder. I'm sure it has something to do with Coldfusion automatically looking for an index.cfm even when the path doesn't include an actual file name.

How can I write an addition to my script where if there is no .cfm in the CGI.Referer, it can search the directory and capture the default file set to load or at least search for an occurrence of index.cfm or default.cfm?

Here is a block of code handling the referer element:

```
   <!---Variable declared and set to empty--->
    <cfset referer_path_and_file = "">
    <cfset referer_path = "">
    <cfset referer_file_name = "">
    <cfset script_path_and_file = "">
    <cfset script_path = "">
    <cfset script_file_name = "">

    <cfif cgi.HTTP_REFERER neq ''>
      <!--- all of this will fail if there is no referer, for instance, if they bookmark the page --->
      <!--- cgi.HTTP_REFERER may contain URL parameters, so let's strip those --->
      <cfset referer_path_and_file = ListFirst(CGI.HTTP_REFERER, "?")>
      <!--- now let's get just the path, stripping out the web server info --->
      <cfset referer_path = ListDeleteAt(CGI.HTTP_REFERER, ListLen(CGI.HTTP_REFERER, "/"), "/")>
      <cfset referer_path = ReplaceNoCase(referer_path, "https", "", "All")>
      <cfset referer_path = ReplaceNoCase(referer_path, "http", "", "All")>
      <cfset referer_path = ReplaceNoCase(referer_path, "://machine1.fss.com", "", "All")>
      <cfset referer_path = ReplaceNoCase(referer_path, "://www_dev.fss.com", "", "All")>
      <cfset referer_path = ReplaceNoCase(referer_path, "://www.fss.com", "", "All")>
      <cfset referer_path = ReplaceNoCase(referer_path, "://10.11.2.60/", "", "All")>
      <cfset referer_path = referer_path & "/">
      <cfset referer_path = ReplaceNoCase(referer_path, "/", "\", "All")>
      <!--- now let's remove everything but the file name --->
      <cfset referer_file_name = ListLast(referer_path_and_file, "/")>
      <!--- and that leaves us with these variables set --->
     <!--- referer_path_and_file = "#referer_path_and_file#"<br />
      referer_path = "#referer_path#"<br />
      referer_file_name = "#referer_file_name#"<br />
      <br />--->
    </cfif>
<!---Directory Stripping And Modifier Block Goes Here--->
<!---Set CGI System Variables--->
<cfset currentHeader = CGI.HTTP_REFERER >
<cfset currentScriptPage = CGI.SCRIPT_NAME > 
<!---Set currentScriptPage as command line directory string and delcare new variable "reverseScriptPage"--->
<cfset reverseScriptPage = ReReplace(#currentScriptPage#, "/", "\","ALL")>
<!---Set reverseScriptPage value as newly format command line directory structure--->
<cfset newScriptPage = ListSetAt(#reverseScriptPage#, 1, "#reverseScriptPage#") >
```

The code just strips the CGI script and referer variables of their http web references and then strips the directory structure portion and inserts the .cfm file name and original directory structure into the DB table, but not before reversing the / characters to \ because they want to be able to setup a script which will loop through the table and see something like "\admin\controls\" and auto create those directories, then copy the example.cfm page into that directory. The aim is to 1.) determine which of the 500 cfc/cfm files are still used in the application, then copy them and their directory structure to a new location, and redesign those files in a new technology that isn't Coldfusion.

Update:  I'm running into an issue with my code. When I test it, it works well, truncating the http domain portion. However once its operating live under the web server, it doesn't truncate the url despite there being a ReplaceNoCase method to do so:

Under the web root in the wwwroot root, it works well giving this output:
refererPage: testFiles.cfm  refererPath = testCodes\MVC

Under the live site I get this:
refererPage: client_display refererPath: **:\dev.fss.com\admin_area** 
despite having this line in my code:

Any idea why?

Comment: Please clarify.  In the first paragraph you are talking about the cgi scope and in the second, it's the url scope.

Comment: Are you tracking real users? The CGI.HTTP_REFERER is only set when a link is followed. It can also be blocked by things like Norton Internet Security so you can't guarantee it'll exists. The HTTP_REFERER shouldn't be affected by the running the default directory index file.

Comment: _"I'm sure it has something to do with Coldfusion automatically looking for an index.cfm even when the path doesn't include an actual file name"_ More like the web server default file list.

Comment: Its an internal application on a server. Management wants to see what pages get hit and what pages people go to next because there are 500 cfc/cfm files. Their idea is to monitor those variables and store then in a DB table along with the path name. Last night they ran into the issue of how the application is designed that if they click to a directory called Project, it directs them there but doesn't log the page they are going to in the Project folder.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you might miss all the cfc files with this approach.  Those are often accessed with createobject or cfobject inside the cfm files.

Comment: "Management wants to see what pages get hit and what pages people go to next". You know the web server can / does pretty much log this for you, right? It can log every request made.

Comment: I tried to express that to them but they want it the way they want it which has led to the above code.

Answer (score 1):

If your cgi.http_referrer variable does not not contain .cfm, you can use the DirectoryExists function on your referer_path variable.  If it returns true, you can use the DirectoryList function or cfdirectory tag to search for an occurrence of index.cfm or default.cfm.

Answer (score 0):

they may have this going through a framework (like a model view controller). Without knowing more about the URL structures and the naming conventions.

And without knowing more I would say you are dealing with dynamic content (especially if it is going through index.cfm). Even in an engine with 500 pages, there is a unique identifier and that should be your target not a file.  So we may assume there are no files at all and we are just calling parts and pieces from here and there to make a page based on your URL querystring, local variables and/or form variables.

So tables are your friends.  Examine your URL structure, try to break down the parameters, search the code base for those parameters and once you have located the area that builds the pages then somewhere there set your tracking tools (a bit higher up stream in the page request stream).

Maybe with some code snippets we could give you a more precise answer but for now this should at least get you looking at your code base for clues.